# Meaning of Math Symbols in the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, notation

I am learning the fundamental theorem of calculus, and in it I came across this symbol Š. My book does not explain what it means.

This is where I saw the symbol. What does this mean?  [image]

**What does Š mean?**

Comment: It means the typesetter didn't check the copy to see if "$\leq$" was encoded correctly

Comment: So its just a typo?

Comment: What book is this?!  The typesetting looks *terrible*.  Since it seems that the author doesn't know how to do proper mathematical typesetting, I would imagine that K B Dave's explanation is quite likely.

Comment: Yeah, this is the integral mean value theorem

Comment: Yeah Its just a typo

Comment: Now I'm curious -- what book is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This symbol should be ≤ (or $\leq$ if the first one doesn't render): that is, "is less than or equal to". The typesetter for this book clearly hasn't done a very good job of it, and seems to have run into an encoding issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a misprint or an encoding problem the actual notation is ' ≤ '.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the author made a mistake and meant to write $\leq$.